# How do I set image axis range by using mataplotlib.imsave

Tags: image, matplotlib

I generated an RGB image which is in pandas.DataFrame type. The image could be showed well by using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(). Now I want to save the image to local disk.

I skimmed the docs of matplotlib and found that ply.imsave() could do this. But imsave() don't have a parameter that could set the axis range.

I tried plt.axis() but it doesn't work. Any tips here please?

The code is below:

```
def _load_img(self, df):
    imgUnpadded = np.zeros((3, self.img_x_max, self.img_y_max))
    imgUnpadded[0,:,:],xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(df['img_x'],
                                       df['img_y'],
                                       bins = [self.img_x_max, self.img_y_max])
    imgUnpadded[1,:,:],xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(df['img_x'],
                                       df['img_y'],
                                       bins = [self.img_x_max, self.img_y_max],
                                       weights = df['u'])
    imgUnpadded[2,:,:],xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(df['img_x'],
                                       df['img_y'],
                                       bins = [self.img_x_max, self.img_y_max],
                                       weights = df['v'])
    return imgUnpadded

def _img_normlization(self, imgUnpadded, ymax, xmax):
    if 'pad' in self.img_params:
        pad = self.img_params['pad']
    else:
        pad = 50
    img0 = np.pad(imgUnpadded[0,:,:],pad,'constant',constant_values = 0)
    img = np.zeros((3, xmax+2*pad, ymax+2*pad))
    for ic in range(1,3):
        img[ic,:,:] = np.pad(imgUnpadded[ic,:,:],pad,'constant',constant_values = 0)
        img[ic,:,:] = np.nan_to_num(img[ic,:,:]/img0)
        img[ic,:,:] -= img[ic,:,:].min()
        img[ic,:,:] /= img[ic,:,:].max()
    img0 = np.nan_to_num(img0/img0)
    img[0,:,:] = img0
    img = np.transpose(img,(1,2,0))
    return img

def _save_img(self, img, i, day, actual_dep_time):
    if 'start_index' in self.img_params:
        output_fn = '%06d' % (i+self.img_params['start_index']) + '_' + day + '_' + actual_dep_time + '.png'
    else:
        output_fn = '%06d' % (i+1) + '_' + day + '_' + actual_dep_time + '.png'
    output_fp = os.path.join(self.save_base_fp, output_fn)
    plt.axis([0, self.img_x_max, 0, self.img_y_max])
    plt.imsave(output_fp, np.transpose(img,(1,0,2)), origin='lower')
```

The 3 functions would be run one by one. The input of _load_img() is a np.DataFrame which have 4 columns ['imgx', 'img_y', 'u', 'v']

Comment: Please show what code you have.

Comment: Show how you run the functions

Comment: Show the instance variables

Comment: It's hard to help you if you don't provide a runnable example.

Comment: One more thing. What is the shape of img before saving? What is img_x_max? img_y_max? It really doesn't matter where the image comes from. What is the actual problem? Are you trying to save a subset?

Comment: Well... I extract the data from a big dataset and save it in a pandas.DataFrame which have 4 columns. I only post 3 relevant functions here because other functions are for data processing. I think the problem is probably at the final stage when calling imsave(), because the image could be plot well by calling imshow(). I was wondering are there some parameters that could set the axis that could apply to the imsave()

Comment: img_x_max and img_y_max is the globa max (x,y). So what i want to do is to generate a series of images with the same figure size and the same axis. but actually part of the images that I get look like be stretched wrongly

Comment: Can you provide some actual numbers?

Comment: Imsave has nothing to do with axes. It just saves a raster of pixels.